# Blockchain app says payment amount is over limit

Tags: blockchain.info

I have the Blockchain app on my iPhone which I've been using regularly for years but which in fact I haven't used for the last 4 months. It currently has around $2000 worth of BTC in my private wallet. I have just gone to make a purchase for goods of around $50. I click on Send, select Private Key Wallet, enter the recipient's address but as I type $50 it tells me in red that I am trying to send an amount over my limit. Can anyone tell me what's happening with this?

Comment: Have you received a huge number of very small payments? Is it possible that most of your UTXOs have tiny amounts and spending them costs more than they are worth?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are trying to send $50 and not 50 Bitcoin